# Illegal constructor when invoking new instance of my typescript object

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexeddb

I have a custom typescript class object:

```
class IndexedDBManager {
 constructor(autoCreateDatabaseAndTable : boolean = false, databaseName : string = null, tableName : string = null, primaryKey : string = null, obtrusiveError: boolean = false) {
      if (!this.VerifyIndexDB()) {
            console.error("IndexedDB is not supported on this browser.");
            if (obtrusiveError) {
                 alert("IndexedDB is not supported on this browser.");
                 return;
            }
      }
      if (autoCreateDatabaseAndTable) {
            this.SetAndCreateDatabase(databaseName, obtrusiveError);
            this.SetAndCreateTable(tableName, primaryKey, obtrusiveError);
      }
 }
...
}
```

When attempt to instantiate a new instance of this class using

```
var myTest = new IndexedDBManager(true, "myTestDB", "myTestTable", "key", true);
```

in the browser console, I get the following console error:

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor.
```

What's going on here and how do I fix this?

Edit: As noted in the comments, removing ALL code from the constructor does not solve the issue.

Comment: It might be something in one of those methods called by the constructor

Comment: Removing all code from the constructor causes the same problem.